# MYSQL Error : More than one primary key, duplicate error

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have table with 2 primary keys.at insertion if one of the 2 keys is duplicated i got error duplicate entry .Why this happens .if any one knows reply?
thanks in advance.

Comment: because primary keys should be unique, you should set the field to AUTO_INCREMENT and let the DB handle the numbering

Comment: Primary key is an identifier. To identify a row in the table, you cannot have 2 or more rows with the same identifier.

Comment: first thanks for reply.but if i dnot want to make it auto increment.?

Comment: @ DanFromGermany thanks,but one of the 2 primary keys is duplicated but the other is not.so?

Comment: If you don't want database to handle the primary key then take care that at every insertion you give a new value... that is not used before.. as primary key need to be unique for every row

Comment: thanks all ,after i edit the indexes to set both to be the primary key.the error gone,i thought that when i make 2 keys as primary this will make them both composite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for composite primary keys. You can only have one primary key in a table. A primary key consists of one or more columns. If a primary key consists of two or more columns it is called a composite primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
  id1 int,
  id2 int,
  primary key (id1, id2)
);
```

If you define a composite primary key with two fields, you can have duplicate values for just one field. It gives error only when both of the keys are same.

Comment: thanks for reply,i thought that when i make 2 keys as primary this will make them both composite.i have edit the indexes and make them both primaty thanks.